# Compute a function for a division an n amount of times

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is really a simple question but I can't wrap my head around it. I need to represent a function to show n divided by 4 a k amount of times. For example:

n/4 (k = 1)

n/4/4 (k = 2)

n/4/4/4 (k = 3)

I just can't think of a way to write this easily.

Comment: $\frac{n}{4^k}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either note that dividing multiple times is the same as multiplying the quotients, thus having $f(x) = x/(4^k) $ for any $k $ you choose.

Or by recursion, setting $f_0(x) = x $ and then $f_k(x) = f_{k-1}(x)/4$

Comment: That what I initially thought as well, n/4^k. However, when working it out by hand I would expect the denominator to be 0.25 when k  = 3. (4/4/4 = .25). However using this logic this would yield me n/4^k = n/4^3 = n/64 which is not the same as .25. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @frillybob in your question, for k=3, you wrote n/4/4/4 and that expression is seen as (((n/4)/4)/4), right? That is very different from n/(4/4/4) which is what you wrote now.

Comment: I do mean (((n/4)/4)/4). I was evaluating things out of order. Very simple mistake. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: @frillybob no problem. If your problem is now solved and the answer was the right one, feel free to accept it so this can be closed.